# Backbone: Rendering Collection View – tagName is ignored

Tags: backbone.js

I am having some difficulties rendering a Backbone Collection View.

In my HTML, I have a div with id `member-list`:

```
<div id="member-list"></div>
```

The view used to hold the actual list is called `MemberListView`:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
var MemberListItemView = require('MemberListItemView');

return Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',

  render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function (item) {
      this.$el.append(new MemberListItemView({ model: item }).render().el);
    }.bind(this));

    return this;
  },
});
```

Each single item is represented by `MemberListItemView`:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
var _ = require('underscore');

return Backbone.View.extend({
  template: '_.template($("#memberItemTemplate").html())',

  tagName: 'li',

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

    return this;
  },
});
```

From a parent view, I invoke `MemberListView` like this:

```
this.list = new MemberListView({ collection: this.collection });
this.list.setElement('#member-list').render();
```

Unfortunately, the HTML output is not correct, the `ul` is missing:

```
<div id="member-list">
  <li>Member</li>
  <li>Member</li>
  <li>Member</li>
</div>
```

I think the problem has something to do with using `setElement` - probably  because there is already `el` or something like this.

How can I add the `<ul>` to the output and force `MemberListView` to not ignore the `tagName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Backbone.View.extend({
  template: '_.template($("#memberItemTemplate").html())',
```

Your tempalte seems to be a string and not a tempalte. I am guessing what you want is something like this:

```
return Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($("#memberItemTemplate").html()),
```

also instead of

```
this.list = new MemberListView({ collection: this.collection });
this.list.setElement('#member-list').render()
```

try

```
this.list = new MemberListView({ collection: this.collection, el: $('#member-list') });
this.list.render();
```